# Error in template(SJ Financial Joomla) in sj_financial/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

Tags: php, templates, joomla, syntax-error

i installed SJ Financial Template joomla on my website caindiagroup.com,
but when i open article blog on my website, it show an error on sj_financial/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php file..

```
Fatal error: Class 'JLayoutHelper' not found in /home/caind126/public_html/templates/sj_financial/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'JLayoutHelper' not found in /home/caind126/public_html/templates/sj_financial/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php on line 27

Fatal error: Class 'JLayoutFile' not found in /home/caind126/public_html/templates/sj_financial/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php on line 103

Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in /home/caind126/public_html/templates/sj_financial/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php on line 104
```

My file Code is

```
`<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  Layout
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;?>
<?php
// Create a shortcut for params.
$params = $this->item->params;
$images = json_decode($this->item->images);
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/html');
$canEdit = $this->item->params->get('access-edit');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
?>
<?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
    <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED'); ?></span>
```

```
    <?php //intro images ?>
    <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>

<div class="article-text">
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_title, $this->item'); ?>

<?php if (!$params->get('show_intro')) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayTitle; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_intro')) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<div class="item-headinfo">
    <?php if (!$params->get('show_intro')) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayTitle; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>

    <?php // to do not that elegant would be nice to group the params ?>

    <?php if (($params->get('show_author')) or ($params->get('show_category')) or ($params->get('show_create_date')) or ($params->get('show_modify_date')) or ($params->get('show_publish_date')) or ($params->get('show_parent_category')) or ($params->get('show_hits'))) : ?>
     <dl class="article-info muted">
     <!--<dt class="article-info-term"><?php //echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_INFO'); ?></dt>-->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_parent_category')) : ?>
            <dd class="parent-category-name">
                <?php $title = $this->escape($this->item->parent_title);
                    $url = '<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->parent_id)) . '">' . $title . '</a>'; ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('link_parent_category')) : ?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $url); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $title); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
            <dd class="create">
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
        <?php echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC'))); ?>
            </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_modify_date')) : ?>
            <dd class="modified">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
            <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_LAST_UPDATED', JHTML::_('date',$this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC'))); ?>
            </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_publish_date')) : ?>
            <dd class="published">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
            <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE', JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_up, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC'))); ?>
            </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_author') && !empty($this->item->author )) : ?>
        <dd class="createdby"> 
            <?php $author =  $this->item->author; ?>
            <?php $author = ($this->item->created_by_alias ? $this->item->created_by_alias : $author);?>

                <?php if (!empty($this->item->contactid ) &&  $params->get('link_author') == true):?>
                    <?php   echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY' , 
                     JHTML::_('link',JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id='.$this->item->contactid),$author)); ?>

                <?php else :?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', $author); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </dd>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php if ($params->get('show_hits')) : ?>
        <dd class="hits">
        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_HITS', $this->item->hits); ?>
        </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_tags', 1)) : ?>
        <dd class="item-tags">
            <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
        </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (($params->get('show_author')) or ($params->get('show_category')) or ($params->get('show_create_date')) or ($params->get('show_modify_date')) or ($params->get('show_publish_date')) or ($params->get('show_parent_category')) or ($params->get('show_hits'))) :?>
    </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php if ($params->get('show_readmore') && $this->item->readmore) :
    if ($params->get('access-view')) :
        $link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid));
    else :
        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
        $active = $menu->getActive();
        $itemId = $active->id;
        $link1 = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&Itemid=' . $itemId);
        $returnURL = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid));
        $link = new JURI($link1);
        $link->setVar('return', base64_encode($returnURL));
    endif; ?>

    <a class="readmore" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"> 
    <?php if (!$params->get('access-view')) :
        echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
    elseif ($readmore = $this->item->alternative_readmore) :
        echo $readmore;
        if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
        echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
        endif;
    elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
        echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE_TITLE');
    else :
        echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE');
        echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
    endif; ?>
        <i class="ico-arrow-right"></i>

    </a>

<?php endif; ?>


</div>

<?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayContent; ?>`
```

Plz help me..

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but you can try to add following line just after `defined('_JEXEC') or die;`

```
require_once(JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries/cms/layout/helper.php');
```